# How to rotate an <img> but just see the white canvas from behind

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate an img in y axis but I don't want to see the photo when my img rotete 180 degree. i just want to see the white blank object. The sample code is like below.

```
    <div class="playSheet">
    <img src="./images/tile000.png" alt="">
    </div>

    .playSheet img:hover{
    transform: rotatey(180deg);
    transition: 2s;
    }
```

https://navidiuming.github.io/FindPairsOfCards/